# C# if statement on gridviewdatacolumn

Tags: c#, gridview

i have code like this

```
....
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="NO_APPEL" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="N° Appel">
                       <DataItemTemplate>

                 IF DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NO_APPEL") == NULL  
                      THEN i don't want to show the link (a href)
                  ELSE
                      show the link (a href)

                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OnMoreInfoClick_Appel(this, '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NO_APPEL") %>')">Plus d'info</a>

                </DataItemTemplate>
......
```

Comment: @Anuraj At first view it seems like a horrible post with no specific question, but if you really look at it you find the question is crystal clear. In the edit Asif took away the "thanks in advance bla bla bla" line (nice thing to do) but that way the post seems rude and effortless.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution

```
<%# SpecificFunction(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NO_APPEL"))%>

public string SpecificFunction(string value)
{
   ...... //your treatment
   return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NO_APPEL") == NULL ? 
      String.Empty 
      : 
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OnMoreInfoClick_Appel(this, '<%#
      DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.NO_APPEL") %>')">Plus d'info</a> 
 %>
```

Of course it should be a one liner, but I splitted it for clarity.